# Superheroine and Supervillainess who oppose each other in day time jobs

Tags: story-identification, movie, female-characters

A long time ago I saw a movie on television about a superheroine and a supervillainess.

I do not remember much, but in the superheroine's day job her boss was the supervillainess. And the villainess was totally bossing the heroine around.

Despite encountering each other in their paper-thin disguise as superheroes, they did not recognize each other in their day job.

It was either a deliberate parody, or was very cheesy. All I remember it was hilarious.

This story is older than 2005, I saw it on German TV.

Comment: No idea, but it sounds like a fun show to watch.

Comment: You may want to check out the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/), for ideas on additional info you may recall and be able to edit into the question.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a lot like the 1997 TVM version of [Justice League of America.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_of_America_(film)) Except that the villain is male.

It is a very bad movie, a candidate for the worst Superhero movie of all time. Very cheesy indeed. Poorly done special effects, badly written, and characters that barely resemble the comic.

The costumes are badly done, and are definitely paper-thin disguises.

The film mainly centres on Ice, who is newly discovering her superpowers. The villain is her boss.

Answer (score -1):

Although you said it was older than 2005, you might double check My Super Ex-Girlfriend: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0465624/ which has a lot of elements you described.

It's a comedy, the woman and her boss in civilian life are secretly and unknowingly the hero and the villain, and it the character threw a lot of folks around, especially the protagonist.

Comment: Er... how is Professor Bedlam considered to be her her boss?

Comment: I may be misremembering the movie, but without spoiling it, I wasn't referring to Professor Bedlam as the villain. And it may be coworkers?